# Tomcat memory leak - Stopping Guava Finalizer thread

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, guava, bonecp

I have a Spring web application running on Tomcat.

When trying to shutdown Tomcat with the `shutdown.sh` script, the java process doesn't end because it has a Thread that's still running. The `catalina.log` contains

```
Jul 22, 2013 2:07:50 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/myapp] appears to have started a thread named [com.google.common.base.internal.Finalizer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

Apparently `BoneCP` has some `Guava` integration that causes this thread to block. Is there a clean or intended way to kill this thread?

Comment: get the pid and kill it ?

Comment: I'd rather do it gracefully and without extra commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an open [issue](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=92) on Guava for this problem - the issue itself is pretty old but if you check the latest comments you'll see some suggestions from other BoneCP users to resolve this issue

Also check this other [issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/detail?id=288) and this [patch](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/attachmentText?id=288&aid=2880093000&name=GUICE_288_static_concrete_class.patch&token=9Nt1JSn8lvwmHHplWBclQZ7hl2o%3A1374518652770)

Comment: I've looked at your first link, but I don't know how to get a reference to `FinalizableReferenceQueue`. Also, in the Guava (13.0.1) source I'm looking at, `FinalizableReferenceQueue` doesn't implement `Closeable`.

Comment: FinalizableReferenceQueue does implement Closeable in guava 15.0. BoneCP >=0.8.0-rc3 calls queue.close() explicitly anyway now.